# Django: No ReverseMatch. How to reverse to the previous URL?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a model class `Client` and the URL for this model object is

```
<local_server>/object_id/
```

Where `object_id` is the `id` of the object of model `Client`.

Now, when I am at this URL, there is a button on the page called `Add Installment` to add the installment for that particular `Client`. When I click on this button it takes me to the following URL:

```
<local_server>/object_id/add_installment
```

Now if I add the new installment, it works fine. But the `Add Installment` page has two buttons, `Add` and `Cancel`. I want that If I click on `Cancel` it should get back to the following URL:

```
<local_server>/object_id/
```

And for that I have the following template for adding installment, where you can see the `Cancel` button.

installment_form.html

```
{% extends "client_management_system/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content_section">
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"> Add New Installment</legend>
        {{ form|crispy }}
      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Add Installment</button>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" type = "submit" href="{%  url 'client_details' object.id %}" >Cancel</a>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

In the `Cancel` button, `client_details` is the name of the URL `<local_server>/object_id`. I have written the `object.id` in that line, but when I click on `Add Installment` I am getting the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /1/Add-Installment
Reverse for 'client_details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/Add-Installment
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'client_details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']
Exception Location: /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  /anaconda3/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.10
Python Path:    
['/Users/razajaved/Documents/installment_plan',
 '/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip',
 '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6',
 '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aeosa']
Server time:    Wed, 21 Apr 2021 20:49:32 +0000
```

Can someone please help me in this?

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with the variable `object.id` in the template, it might not be the "object.id" you expect

Comment: yes it seems like object.id is referencing to the id of the installment object which was not created because I clicked on Cancel.

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to do this:

Go back to the previous URL `<local_server>/object_id/` by replacing the following line in my html file:

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-danger" type = "submit" href="{%  url 'client_details' object.id %}" >Cancel</a>
```

with this:

```
<input type=button class="btn btn-outline-danger" value="Cancel" onClick="window.history.back();return false;">
```

OR with this:

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-danger" type = "submit" href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Cancel</a>
```